# R - Cascading numbers down to cover NAs

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with many NAs. I want to use the number before the NA to replace it. Specifically,

```
Date Price
1    2.1
2    NA
3    2.4
```

I want to use '2.1' to replace the NA below it. I'm storing my data in a data.table and it contains 700 million observations. I know how to do it with a forloop, but it's taking a very long time. Is there a way to improve the speed?

Comment: Try `zoo::na.locf()`

Comment: Trying it now. Seems to work.